# CSS styling for IP address display is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: IP address display]

I was [asked by @pnuts on chat to look into a potential spammer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23322145#23322145) in our review queue. It seems however that the CSS styling for the IP address shown after clicking "show IP" next to "anonymous user" shows it with an unreadable, bright orange background.

Can someone at SE please fix this? :)

Comment: I think the higher-ups will need browser and OS information from you. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup; the moderator-specific JS here was assuming the text was black, without consideration for site-specific themes; this should be fixed next build.